# How to get the values of the checked radio button in iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, radio-button

I have here a page with iframe. Inside the iframe, it will display all the questions in multiple choice. The problem is that I don't know how to get all the values of the checked radio buttons inside the iframe. The button is in the parent page (I haven't included it yet).

This is the screen capture of my page (questions.php):

[image: Webpage]

This is my iframe code from questions.php:

```
<div class="question-display test">
     <iframe src="questions/frame.php" height="500px" width="100%">

     </iframe>
</div>
```

This is my frame.php (displaying all the questions)

```
<?php
                include('config.php');
                $view_questions=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND()");
                $count=mysql_num_rows($view_questions);
                    $i=1;
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($view_questions))
                    {

                ?>
        <div class="questions-contents text-size test" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <p align="justify"><strong><?php echo $i;?>.)</strong> <?php echo $row['QUESTION'];?></p>
        </div>


        <div class="answer-indent" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px;">    
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>" value="1" data-toggle="radio">
                <class="color" style="color: gray;"><?php echo $row['ANSWER_1'];?></class="color">
            </label>

            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>" value="2" data-toggle="radio">
                <class="color" style="color: gray;"><?php echo $row['ANSWER_2'];?></class="color">
            </label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>" value="3" data-toggle="radio">
                <class="color" style="color: gray;"><?php echo $row['ANSWER_3'];?></class="color">
            </label>

            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>" value="4" data-toggle="radio">
                <class="color" style="color: gray;"><?php echo $row['ANSWER_4'];?></class="color">
            </label>

            <label class="radio" style="display: none;" >
                <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>" value="5" data-toggle="radio" checked>

            </label>
        </div>
            <?php
                    $i++; }
            ?>
```

Before I make my frame.php inserted to iframe from the questions.php page, I have a php codes for checking the answers of the users (the checked radio buttons).

```
$questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($questions)){
    if($_POST[$row['QUESTION_NO']]==$row["ANSWER"])
    {
        $score++;
    } 
    elseif($_POST[$row['QUESTION_NO']]==5)
    {
        $unanswered++;
    }
    else
    {
        $wrong_score++;
    }
}
```

Please help me, I'm doing this since yesterday but I didn't get it. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What's the reason for including the form via iframe?

Comment: for having a scroll bar in order to prevent a long page (in page height).

Comment: you can do this with a div container and setting the overflow via CSS. the reason why i'm saying this is b/c I don't think it's possible to use form data from an iframe (though i could be wrong). example: http://jsfiddle.net/ankpbwk9/

Comment: @Melissa Thank you so much for your suggestion. This is what I'm looking for. I used iframe because I thought it is the only way for having a scroll bar and I never wonder if there is another way for it. God Bless you! :)

Comment: I dont see you have the form element, you should have it and also define the action and method it uses,so it will post the data and to the currect page with the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

You can give id to your iframe and access its elements.

`document.getElementById('frameid').contentWindow.document.getElementById('abc')`

Where `abc` is your radio button element.

Then you can do whatever you want to do with element.

But seriously, you can do the same thing in Div also with proper css.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have you seen my php codes for checking the checked radio buttons? Will that be useful/working in my iframe?

Answer (score 0):

the iframe form action should be the iframe parent url

```
<form action="parenturl.php" method="POST">
```

When you dont add the action attribute to your form element the default action will
be submitting the form to the current page by GET method, so when you trying to
view the post data in the parent there is nothing to show because the data was posted to the
iframe itself and not to the parent.

so make sure you define the method and and action.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give same name to all the checkboxes. And you can allot the question no. for their id

So the form will be

```
    <div class="answer-indent" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px;">    
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="question" id="<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>" value="1" data-toggle="radio">
                    <class="color" style="color: gray;"><?php echo $row['ANSWER_1'];?></class="color">
                </label>

<label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="question" id="<?php echo $row['QUESTION_NO'];?>" value="2" data-toggle="radio">
                <class="color" style="color: gray;"><?php echo $row['ANSWER_2'];?></class="color">
            </label>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </div>
```

So we can get the checked box values using simple snippet.
 showing below

```
<?php

$values = $_POST['question'];

// optional

foreach ($values as $selected){
echo $selected."<br />";

}


?>
```

Please try this